# Probability of selecting 3 candidates

Tags: probability

In one exam , $75$% of the candidates have passed the exam  and the upper quartile for the marks is $46$ and only $25$ %got a merit score .

3 candidates are selected at random , find the probability that all of them have passed the exam but only two have got a merit score .

My turn is
0.75 * 0.25* 0.25 * 3 = 0.140625

Is it correct ?

Comment: Does being in the top quartile mean a merit score? Can you say $25\%$ passed with merit, $50\%$ passed without merit and $25\%$ failed?

Comment: If so, you might want to change your $0.75$ to $0.75-0.25=0.5$, since one of the candidates passed but did not get into the top quartile.

Comment: Thanks , i got it @Hery